# mysql unique key and index

Tags: mysql

in MySQL, If I create a unique key on two columns, say

UNIQUE KEY `my_key` (`column1`, `column2`)

is it necessary to build another key on `column1`? My goal is to have column1 and column2 to be unique, and I'll do lots of selects keyed by column1.

Comment: just did an experiment using EXPLAIN, it seems I don't have to create another key on column1, as mysql will use the unique key when doing select keyed by column1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not necessary because an index on (column1, column2) can be used instead of an index of column1 alone.

You might want to make a new index on just column two though as the index (column1, column2) is not good when searching only for (column2).

Answer (score 8):

No, your `my_key` index takes care of any queries on `column1` or conditions on `column1` AND `column2`. However, if you make queries on only `column2`, then you should add an additional index for `column2` to be able to query it efficiently.

Furthermore, if both `column1` and `column2` are unique, then you might want to consider using something like

```
[...]
UNIQUE(column1),
UNIQUE(column2),
PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2);
```

This ensures that both `column1` and `column2` are unique, and any query selecting only `column1` and `column2` can be retrieved using index-only access.

Answer (score 2):

A UNIQUE-index is a [btree-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree). This index is sorted and that's why you don't need a second index on the first colummn. The sort order of the combination will also work for only the first column, but not for only the second column.